# How to express Result<Value, Error: Errortype> in a method signature

Tags: swift, alamofire

I've been trying to make an Alamofire upgrade from 2.0 to 3.0. One of the methods contains this signature:

`func standardResponse(request: NSURLRequest?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, result: Result<AnyObject>, success: (object: AnyObject?) -> Void, failure: (error: ServerError) -> Void)`

There's an error pointing at `Result<AnyObject>`, stating that `generic type 'Result' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)`

Alright, so I put in 2. According to the [Alamofire 3.0 migration guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md), **Result** has changed to accommodate an extra `Error: ErrorType` parameter. I tried this next:

`Result<AnyObject, Error>`

This time the error was that `Error does not conform to protocol ErrorType`.

So maybe this?

`Result<AnyObject, Error: ErrorType>`

No cigar. Please help me understand.

Comment: Probably just `Result<AnyObject, ErrorType>`.

Comment: `Using 'ErrorType' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'ErrorType' is not supported` @EricD.

Comment: This new error message made me think of a suggestion: make a new error type and use it. Like `enum ET: ErrorType { case xxx case yyy }` then `Result<AnyObject, ET>`. If it works I'll make it my answer, but for now I'm not sure.

Comment: @EricD. Nice idea, it shut up the compiler. Now to understand how to use this properly. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm posting it as an answer for better visibility even if it's probably not a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [looks like](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#result-type) the second parameter has to be an object conforming to `ErrorType`.

So you could for example create your own error type with an enum like this:

```
enum MyErrorType: ErrorType { 
    case SomeError 
    case SomeOtherError 
}
```

Then use it the way the compiler asks:

```
Result<AnyObject, MyErrorType>
```